# Entity Framework Core - How to include/populate a navigation property with custom(1-to-1) query in EF?

Tags: database, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

How to include/populate a navigation property with custom(1-to-1) query in EF?

e.g.

```
public class Item {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("Id")]
     public ItemCost LatestCost {get; set; }
}

public class ItemCost {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime? To { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
}
```

Goal is to populate the LatestCost property of the Item with it's latest cost from ItemCosts. How is this being accomplished with EF or what's your take on this?

Is it possible to do a custom query within .Include/.ThenInclude methods?
e.g.

```
.ThenInclude(a => { a.LatestCost = (from a _db.ItemCosts 
                                    where... select a).SingleOrDefault() })...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a virtual get-only property. Your nav property should really be an `ICollection<ItemCost>`. In this example I'm assuming the `Id` property in the `ItemCost` class is the id of the related `Item`, but it's not clear. Tip: using `nameof(property)` instead of hard-coding the property name will allow the compiler to catch errors with the name if you were to change it for some reason. The `[NotMapped]` attribute tells Entity Framework to not try and map the property to a database field.

```
public class Item {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ItemCost> ItemCosts {get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual ItemCost LatestCost
    {
        get
        {
            return ItemCosts.OrderByDescending(x => x.From).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}

public class ItemCost {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime? To { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Id))]
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Will try this later. Thank you.

Comment: This works for me. The tips are nice too. Thank you.

Comment: Does this solution require that the ItemCosts collection is fully fetched from the database to get the latest cost?

Comment: @Codemunkie no, this will result in a `SELECT TOP 1...` query.